# Why the width between EditText and NavigationIcon is not equal

Tags: android, toolbar

I am customising a toolbar, but the width between `EditText` and `NavigationIcon` is not equal.

[image]

This is my layout file.

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/toolbar"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/main_header_bg"
android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">


   <TextView
       android:id="@+id/tv_title"
       android:layout_width="wrap_content"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:layout_gravity="center"
       android:ellipsize="end"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textColor="#333333"
       android:textSize="18sp"
       android:visibility="gone"/>

   <EditText
       android:id="@+id/et_search"
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="40dp"
       android:background="@drawable/white_round_bg"
       android:drawableLeft="@drawable/ic_search"
       android:drawablePadding="4dp"
       android:hint="search enjoyours"
       android:padding="4dp"
       android:maxLines="1"
       android:textColorHint="#AEAEAE"
       android:textSize="14sp"
       android:visibility="gone"/>

</android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar>
```

How do I change the width between EditText and NavigationIcon like the width EditText and  between the right item.

Comment: then why is that text view right before edit text?

Comment: @xFighter 
The TextView is hidden when Editext is displayed  `  public void showSearch() {
        mTitle.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        mSearchEditText.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
    }`

Comment: getSupportActionBar().setDisplayShowTitleEnabled(false);

Comment: @xFighter 
It does not work for me

Answer (score 3, accepted):

add the following things to your toolbar

```
app:contentInsetLeft="0dp" 
app:contentInsetStart="0dp" 
app:contentInsetStartWithNavigation="0dp"
```

Answer (score 0):

Write these two property in your Toolbar.

```
android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
```

**Like this**

```
<android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/toolbar"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/main_header_bg"
    android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
    android:contentInsetLeft="0dp"
    android:contentInsetRight="0dp"
    app:titleTextColor="@android:color/white">
```

I hope it will solve your problem. But Now I am unable to test this code.